# Datadog: Persisting User Session Data

Tags: datadog

I want to export user session data from Datadog and store it in a remote location I.e., to an AWS S3 bucket in .CSV or .TXT file format. The reason I want to do this is because the retention for user session data by Real User Monitoring (RUM) Browser Data is only 30 days, currently, and I need a time series that displays 12 months of user session data (user info, location). If there is a log on the server where the Datadog agent is running, I can extract it from there, using a script. However, I am unsure if this is the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the list rum events api endpoint to query for sessions to export them elsewhere.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/rum/#get-a-list-of-rum-events

Comment: Thanks. But what would the resulting URL look like? I want to call the total number of user session for a particular application for the day prior I.e. for yesterday.